# Passing arguments to a function from list using Threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to pass arguments to a function from a list using threads in python 
(Note:The values to the function should not be hard-coded and all the elements of the list will be passed.)
Please look at the sample code here:

```
from threading import Thread
list=['john','doe','srav','dev','app']
def m1(name,prefix):
    for ele in range(2):
        print(name +prefix)

def main1():
    t1=Thread(target=m1,args=('abcd','john'))
    t2 = Thread(target=m1, args=('abcd', 'doe'))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main1()
```

Here i hard-coded the values to the function ('john','doe')instead of that pass from the list and all the elements will be passed.

Comment: Looks like you want an executor. It will let you map the function to each list element in a separate thread.

Comment: Mad, can you provide sample code to do that i am new to python

Comment: I'll do something in a bit

Answer (score 3):

Your tasks are well suited for use with the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module. In particular, [`Executor.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) applies a function to the elements of an iterable.

You can use something similar to the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) example in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat

names = ['john', 'doe', 'srav', 'dev', 'app']
def m1(name, prefix):
    for _ in range(2):
        print(name + prefix)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    executor.map(m1, repeat('abcd', len(names)), names)
```

If you find the `repeat` syntax to be awkward, you have a couple of alternatives:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    for name in names:
        executor.submit(m1, 'abcd', name)
```

OR

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
    executor.map(lambda name: m1('abcd', name), names)
```

In all cases, the `with` block will implicitly call [`executor.shutdown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown), which will wait for all the tasks to complete.

As a rule, don't call a variable `list`: it will shadow the name of the builtin class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I completely understand what you are looking to achieve. My understanding is that you want to start a separate thread for each value in your list, so each value gets processed "in parallel". I modified your `main1` function to do so:

```
def main1():
  threads = [Thread(target=m1,args=('abcd',x)) for x in list]
  for thread in threads: thread.start()
  for thread in threads: thread.join()
```

`threads = [Thread(target=m1,args=('abcd',x)) for x in list]` creates a separate thread for each value in the list.

`for thread in threads: thread.start()` starts each thread.

`for thread in threads: thread.join()` makes sure each thread is finished before returning from the `main1` function (if you would rathee return immediately, just delete this line).